# How can I get a TNS for toad for oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, toad

I installed Toad for Oracle, but I can not use it since I must have a TNS, could any one help me through this. how can I create a tns for me so I can start creating tables.

Comment: What do you mean by TNS? Do you have an Oracle client installed or do you only have Toad? It's not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Do you have a database to use or do you need to install one as well? If you have a client already and a database you can use then see kevinsky's answer. If you need a database and/or client then you'll need to do some additional work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toad will not install without an Oracle client being installed on the same machine first.  This will have created a sample TNSNAMES.ora file.

- Use search to find it and add the host name and Database name.
- It should be located in something like C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin.
- Or use a direct connection.  Open Toad and create a new connection using the host name (windows machine name) and the database name.  Sometimes you have to add the domain.
  For example  yourdatabase.yourdomain.local